# Computer-controlled portable reed organ?

Tags: instruments, electronics, organ

The "[Melauton](http://logosfoundation.org/instrum_gwr/melauton.html)" is a  computer-controlled reed organ built from a melodica. Is there any record of similar instruments being built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- [Device Orchestra](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDwMh0pu1iSXeKx7qmqjIQA)
  uses electric toothbrushes, handheld printers, etc.
- [The Floppotron](https://www.youtube.com/user/sh4dowww90) is a giant array
  of floppy disk drives.
- [Hard disks and scanners](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0F586E90FA39E781)
  have been used too.
- A terrifying collection of [plush toys](https://www.lookmumnocomputer.com/furby-organ).
- A [piano](https://ablinger.mur.at/speaking_piano.html) that can speak human languages.